# How to find the factorial of 5 using NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, factorial

I have just started to learn NASM using tutorialspoint's online Asm Compiler (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php).

My first warmup is to write a code that calculates the factorial of 5. Here is my try:

```
section .text
    global _start      
_start:     
    mov eax, 1      ;a = 1
    mov ebx, 1      ;f = 1
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    
l1:
    mul ebx        ; f = f*a
    inc eax        ; a++
    cmp eax, 5     ; if a<=5
    jle l1         ; jump to l1

section .data
msg db 'Factorial 5 is:',0xa    
len equ $ - msg
```

It doesn't print any value out, can anyone give me a hint on what's the problem? Thank you.

Comment: You know EAX=1 is SYS_exit, right?  So `int 0x80` just exits your program.  Single-step your code with a debugger.  And of course it's not going to print anything out if you don't make any `write` system calls or call printf or anything.

Comment: Since that online IDE doesn't appear to have a debugger, it's useless for learning asm.  It's a waste of your own time (and everyone else's) to have to ask Stack Overflow questions about things that would be completely obvious when single-stepping with a debugger. 
 IIRC, https://onlinegdb.com/ has an asm mode, but I forget if it has NASM or just GAS, and IDK if it supports 32-bit mode instead of native 64-bit x86-64.  Linux is free, and NASM + text-mode GDB are pretty lightweight; a local install should would make a lot of sense.

Comment: Could just do `mov eax,5*4*3*2` - might be faster.

Comment: `mul ebx        ; f = f*a` is wrong, if you consider `f` in `ebx` and `a` in `eax`. What it actually does is `a = f * a`. (Plus writing the upper half to `edx` of course.) If you want to multiply into `ebx` use `imul ebx, eax`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the mul operation. In assembly you want to stick to simplicity and avoid division, multiplication and floating point unless you have no other choice.

```
5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 = 5 * 3 * 2 * 2 * 2 = (5 * 2 + 5 ) * 2 * 2 * 2
```

So, to compute this:

```
5 << 1
ADD 5
<< 3
```

No looping or multiplication necessary. If you are going to use a loop (or if that is the point of the lesson), normally in assembly you compare to zero, so you count down, not up.

Using a debugger is essential in assembly. There are some structural issues with your code that stepping through with a debugger will reveal. You can't just use the online system alone. You have to set up a debugger on your computer.

Comment: `>>` is right shift, looks like you mean left.  (or `lea ebx, [ebx + ebx*2]` since this is an x86 question)

Comment: @PeterCordes oops, fixing it.

Comment: Of course, if you're going to special-case one small factorial instead of doing the exercise to learn to write loops, then it's pointless to do any computation at run-time at all.  `mov eax, 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1` assembles to `mov    eax,0x78`.  Or you could even use `%rep` and `%assign` to do an assemble-time factorial "loop", updating a NASM preprocessor variable which you then use as `mov eax, fact`.

Comment: Of course even at run-time for the general case you wouldn't want `mul`, you'd want the faster `imul ebx, eax` (which is what that code in the question seems to think mul is going to do, based on it incrementing eax...)

Comment: And BTW, integer multiplication is not slow on modern x86.  Zen, and Intel for several generations, run it with 3 cycle latency (and 1/clock throughput), same as popcnt on tzcnt on Intel.  Integer division is still slow, and not fully pipelined, so it's not really sensible to lump imul in with div/idiv.  Also, floating-point is not slow if you use it carefully.  4 cycle latency and 2/clock throughput for FP ops other than division is very good for number-crunching.  Getting data back and forth between integer and FP costs instructions and should be avoided, of course.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's not about efficiency. The problem with MUL is managing the carry which creates complexity which can in some cases be avoided if the problem can be solved with addition (or by shifting). As I said in my answer, the secret to reliable assembly programming is simplicity and clarity.

Comment: You mean the high-half output in EDX?  That's not just "carry", it's fully part of the product.  Anyway, yeah, you don't want that, which is why I commented that you'd want 2-operand `imul ebx, eax` which only writes the result to EBX just like `add ebx, eax` would, instead of using EAX as an implicit source and EDX:EAX as an implicit destination.  Not having to write a high half is what makes `imul reg,reg` a bit faster than `mul reg`. https://uops.info/